# Adding layer group using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, group-layer

How can I create a new group in the layer manager using python code?

Answer (score 34):

## Adding groups to the Layers Panel

Using the new Layer tree (introduced since QGIS v.2.4 and available for QGIS v3.x) you can add a group to the QGIS ToC this way:

```
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
myGroup1 = root.addGroup("My Group 1")
```

If you want to add it to a particular position in the ToC, use:

```
myGroup1 = root.insertGroup(2, "My Group 1")
```

## Adding groups into other groups

You can even create nested groups (a group into a group):

```
myGroupA = myGroup1.addGroup("My Group A")
```

If you need to first find an existing group where to put your new group, use this:

```
myOriginalGroup = root.findGroup("My existing group") # We assume the group exists
myNewGroup = myOriginalGroup.addGroup("My New Group")
```

---

You can learn more on Layer tree handling [here](http://www.lutraconsulting.co.uk/blog/2014/07/06/qgis-layer-tree-api-part-1/) and [here](http://www.lutraconsulting.co.uk/blog/2014/07/25/qgis-layer-tree-api-part-2/).

Comment: I cannot find explanation to what ToC means?

Comment: Layer tree, legend, ToC, they are names normally used in GIS when refering to the list of layers and groups in a software.

Answer (score 4):

There is the method [QgsLegendInterface.addGroup( name, expand, parent )](http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsLegendInterface.html#a25a8cf67b140383bab0c75e90a3eb3f8)

Example:

```
iface.legendInterface().addGroup( 'abc')
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the problem was that I did not refer to the interface and used directly QgsLegendInterface.addGroup

Comment: Is there any way to control the position where you insert the menu? The menu is inserted under the shape you have selected. I need to put it above all layers.
Thanks.

Comment: @malagueff, Please edit your question per your comment.