# Inserting group into existing group using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis

I would like add one group into another (already existing one) in layerTreeRoot using PyQGIS.

How can i do it?

[Adding layer group using PyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/66169/adding-layer-group-using-pyqgis) is not the answer to my question, because it allows only to create 2 groups at the same time. Group and sub group.

Comment: Use steps 1 and 2 of this answer (https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/75384/add-layer-to-a-qgis-group-using-python/126587#126587) to get the group (let's call it `myOriginalGroup`) where you want to place your new group. Then just use a `myNewGroup = myOriginalGroup.addGroup("My New Group")` and you're done. See also this answer (https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/66169/adding-layer-group-using-pyqgis/134377#134377) for reference, namely where I mention nested groups.